# After deploying Rails app SQLite3::CantOpenException:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, deployment

I try to deploy a rails app. I using apache with a sqlite3 database. The configuration via passenger and capistrano works well.

But when I start the server and try to modify the database I get the following error:    `SQLite3::CantOpenException: unable to open database file`

I already chmod 777'ing the `production.sqlite3` .
I put `production.sqlite3` in `foofoo/foo/shared` and configured the `database.yml`:

```
production:
adapter: sqlite3
database: /foofoo/foo/shared/production.sqlite3
pool: 5
timeout: 5000
```

(PS rails 3.2.3, ruby 1.9.3, sqlite 3.7.9)

Comment: Do you have access also for every of the subdirectories (/foofoo/foo/shared/)?

Comment: yes, acces to all subdirectories, the owner is www-data

Comment: Did you run `rake db:create`?

Comment: rake db:create db:migrate db:seed RAILS_ENV='production'

Comment: Wait, "I put production.sqlite3 in testcap/shared" and "database: /foofoo/foo/shared/production.sqlite3".
Are you sure it's the right path?

Comment: Oh sorry, that was a typo, everything is in foo

Comment: Maybe there's a problem with SQLite... Does it work with other applications?

Comment: After trying it: There is the same problem (I scaffold a rails app directly on the server)

Comment: ohhh... I guess I solved it... I have to change the owner and the user-group to www-data (default user of apache)

Answer (score 0):

It's because nginx create www-data user, and this user don't have a previlegues to read sqlite3 file and your app...

You need to run this command:

1. `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data rails_project/`
2. `sudo chmod -R 777 rails_project/`